# deep copy Linkedlist without destroying original list and extra storage space (using ANSI C)

Tags: c, algorithm

this linkedlist is different than normal linkedlists is that besides the next pointer, it also has a other pointer that points to another node except itself in the linkedlist.

so what's the best way to deep copy this linkedlist without destroying the original and no extra space?

My approach was simply doing a O(n^2) loop , but should be some smarter way.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for the second pointer?

Comment: I think it's really just to make the problem harder, since this is an interview question

Answer (score 10):

This implementation is completely untested, but the idea is very simple.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    struct node *next;
    struct node *what;
    void *data;
};

struct node *copy(struct node *root) {
    struct node *i, *j, *new_root = NULL;

    for (i = root, j = NULL; i; j = i, i = i->next) {
        struct node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        if (!new_node) abort();
        if (j) j->next = new_node;
        else new_root = new_node;
        new_node->data = i->data;
        i->data = new_node;
    }
    if (j) j->next = NULL;

    for (i = root, j = new_root; i; i = i->next, j = j->next)
        j->what = i->what->data;

    for (i = root, j = new_root; i; i = i->next, j = j->next)
        i->data = j->data;

    return new_root;
}
```

1. Following `->next` on the original list, create a new list that mirrors it.  Mangle `->data` on each node in the old list to point to its corresponding node in the new list.
2. Walk through both lists in parallel and use the earlier mangled `->data` to figure out where the `->what` has gone to in the new list.
3. Walk through both lists in parallel and restore `->data` to its original condition.

Note that this is 3 linear passes, thus its time is O(n), and it does not use any memory beyond what is needed to create the new list.

Comment: This is O(n^2), right? Given a data structure with O(1) lookup (like a hashtable), it's possible to get O(n).

Comment: @Anon I was leaning to a hashtable too, until I read the "no extra space"

Answer (score 3):

Here is a tested C++ implementation of ephemient's solution that uses the next pointer to interleave the nodes in the first pass instead of temporarily taking over data for this purpose. Complexity and space usage remains the same ( O(N) (3 passes) and O(1) space) as ephemients implementation

```
struct Link {
    int data;
    shared_ptr<Link> next;
    weak_ptr<Link> random;
};

shared_ptr<Link> DeepCopy(Link* original) {
    if (!original) return nullptr;

    // 1st Pass:
    // make new nodes and interleave them between the nodes of the original list
    // by changing the next pointers ie:
    //      [1]->[copy of 1]->[2]->[copy of 2]->[3]->[copy of 3] ....
    // during this pass, we will also set the data of new nodes to match the old node
    // being copied.
    Link* node = original;
    while (node) {
        shared_ptr<Link> new_node = make_shared<Link>();
        new_node->data = node->data;
        new_node->next = node->next;
        node->next = new_node;
        node = node->next->next.get(); // skipping the "copy of" node just inserted
    }

    // 2nd Pass:
    // now go through and set the random ptr of the new nodes correctly.
    // i refers to a node on the original list and j the matching node on the new
    // list
    shared_ptr<Link> new_head = original->next; // i.e "copy of 1" is head of new list
    for (Link *i = original; i; i=i->next->next.get()) {
        Link *j = i->next.get(); // new nodes interleave original nodes
        j->random = i->random.lock()->next;
    }

    // 3rd Pass:
    // Restore the original list
    Link* new_node = new_head.get();
    node = original;
    while (node) {
        node->next = new_node->next;

        if (node->next)
            new_node->next = node->next->next;

        node = node->next.get();
        new_node = new_node->next.get();
    }

    return new_head;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could branch your search at every node, and merge the paths back together when you encounter an already-visited node.

Comment: And how do you suggest to keep track of already-visited nodes?  (This is important.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a minor improvement over answer given by @ephemient which does not use the extra `what` pointer. Here is the sketch of an implementation in Scala. The comments assume a list like:

```
+-----------+
|           |
|           v
A --> B --> C----+
^     |     ^    |
|     |     |    |
+-----+     +----+
```

and a `Node` like:

```
class Node {
  var data: Node = null
  var next: Node = null

  def traverse(fn: Node => Unit) {
    var node = this
    while (node != null) {
      fn(node)
      node = node.next
    }
  }
}
```

Here the clone method.

```
def clone(list: Node): Node = {
  if (list == null) return null

  var cloneHead: Node = null

  // first, create n cloned nodes by traversing the original list in O(n) time
  // this step mutates the data pointers of original list
  list traverse { orig =>
    // for each node in original list, create a corresponding cloned node
    val newNode = new Node

    if (orig == list) {
      cloneHead = newNode // store the head node of the cloned list
    }

    // The next pointer of cloned node points to the node pointed to by
    // the corresponding orig node's data pointer i.e. A'.next and A'.data points to C
    newNode.next = orig.data

    // The data pointer on orig node points to the cloned node. i.e. A.data points to A'
    orig.data = newNode
  }

  // then, fix up the data pointers of cloned list by traversing the original 
  // list in O(n) time
  list traverse { orig =>
    clone = orig.data // since the data pointer on orig node points to 
                      // the corresponding cloned node

    // A'.next points to C and C.data points to C', so this sets A'.data to C'
    // this establishes the data pointers of the cloned nodes correctly
    clone.data = if (clone.next == null) null else clone.next.data
  }

  // then, fix up the data pointers of original list and next pointers of cloned list
  // by traversing the original list in O(n) time
  list traverse { orig =>
    clone = orig.data // since the data pointer on orig node still 
                      // points to the corresponding cloned node

    // A.data points to A' and A'.next points to C, so this sets A.data to C, 
    // restoring the original list
    orig.data = if (orig.data == null) null else orig.data.next

    // A.next points to B and B.data points to B', so this sets A'.next to B'
    // since we are working on linked list's next pointers, we don't have to worry
    // about back pointers - A will be handled by this traversal before B, 
    // so we know for sure that that B.data is not "fixed" yet 
    // (i.e. it still points to B') while A'.next is being set
    clone.next = if (orig.next == null) null else orig.next.data
  }

  cloneHead
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is c# version for deep copy of linked list with random pointer:
time complexity is O(N) with constant space (i.e. only space used to create deep copy) (note the same can be achieved with has map with addition O(n) space)

(you may as well refer to my blog : http://codingworkout.blogspot.com/2014/07/deep-copy-with-random-pointer.html)
Gist of the changes:

1. IN the first iteration, create a copy of the given original list such that original node points to the copies
2. In second iteration update the random pointers of the copied list
3. Detach them

   public LinkedListWithRandomPointerNode DeepCopy()
           {
               if(this._first == null)
               {
                   return null;
               }

   ```
           LinkedListWithRandomPointerNode i1 = this._first, i2 = null;
           while(i1 != null)
           {
               //cre new node
               i2 = new LinkedListWithRandomPointerNode();
               i2.e = i1.e;
               i2.next = i1.next;
               //insert it after i1
               i1.next = i2;
               i1 = i2.next;
           }
           LinkedListWithRandomPointerNode firstNodeOfCopiedList = this._first.next;

           i1 = this._first; i2 = i1.next;
           while(i2 != null)
           {
               if(i1.random != null)
               {
                   i2.random = i1.random.next;
               }
               if(i2.next == null)
               {
                   break;
               }
               i1 = i2.next;
               i2 = i1.next;
           }

           i1 = this._first; i2 = i1.next;
           while (i2 != null)
           {
               i1.next = i2.next;
               i1 = i1.next;
               if (i1 != null)
               {
                   i2.next = i1.next;
                   i2 = i2.next;
               }
               else
               {
                   i2.next = null;
                   break;
               }
           }
           return firstNodeOfCopiedList;
       }
   ```

**where**

```
public class LinkedListWithRandomPointerNode
    {
        public int e;
        public LinkedListWithRandomPointerNode next;
        public LinkedListWithRandomPointerNode random;
    }
```

**Unit tests**

```
[TestMethod]
        public void LinkedListWithRandomPointerTests()
        {
            var n = this.DeepCopy();
            Assert.IsNotNull(n);
            var i1 = this._first; var i2 = n;
            while(i1 != null)
            {
                Assert.IsNotNull(i2);
                Assert.IsTrue(i1.e == i2.e);
                if(i1.random != null)
                {
                    Assert.IsNotNull(i2.random);
                    Assert.IsTrue(i1.random.e == i2.random.e);
                }
                i1 = i1.next;
                i2 = i2.next;
            }
        }
        LinkedListWithRandomPointerNode _first = null;
        public LinkedListWithRandomPointer()
        {
            this._first = new LinkedListWithRandomPointerNode() { e = 7 };
            this._first.next = new LinkedListWithRandomPointerNode() { e = 14 };
            this._first.next.next = new LinkedListWithRandomPointerNode() { e = 21 };
            this._first.random = this._first.next.next;
            this._first.next.next.random = this._first;
        }
```